# Excel: How to modify web query based on selected value from list

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to create a web query that takes a value selected from a list?

[image: Example]

In other words, how can I accomplish the equivalent of this:

[image]

Comment: If this is the job U are struggling with then in `A12` make  Drop down and in `D12` write `IF` formula ,,, like `=If(A12="Choice1",  URL1 , IF(,,,,,,,URL 2` .  And literally if stuck with the WEB QUERY then use the POWER QUERY editor !!

Comment: you should be able to use the formula `=HYPERLINK()` or possibly `=webservice()`. To create the URL probably something like: htmlstub&A12.

Comment: @RajeshS , I tried Power Query Editor, but do not see where to modify the URL based on a cell value. See edit above, thank you.